# Using JGitVer in a tycho pomless build

Tags: maven, tycho, jgitver

I would like to use the [jgitver maven plugin](https://github.com/jgitver/jgitver-maven-plugin) to automatic define the version of eclipse plugins, features, repository that are built with [tycho](https://github.com/eclipse/tycho) in [pomless](https://github.com/eclipse/tycho.extras/tree/master/tycho-pomless) mode.

The version management of this 3 plugins are:

- jgitver computes a version depending on git tree and tags, create a logical copy of pom, set the new version and associate the new pom to the current plugin in the maven reactor.
- For tycho, version are defined in pom and in manifest.mf or feature.xml files. A version consistency check is performed.
- When the pom is not defined, pomless maven generates a temporary pom file named .polyglot.build.properties using versions defined in manifest or feature file.
  The input path are defined [here](https://github.com/eclipse/tycho.extras/blob/master/tycho-pomless/src/main/java/org/eclipse/tycho/pomless/TychoModelReader.java) and depends on PolyglotModelUtil.

The easier way would be a Jgitver evolution to locally update the feature.xml and manifest.MF. It would be a bad idea because a local file would be modified that is not compliant with the plugin philosophy.

A better way would be a Jgitver evolution to generate temporary feature.xml and manifest.MF files that would have been updated with the computed version. Then tycho and tycho-pomless should be forced to use them.

It seems to be possible if i succeed in setting a new ModelProcessor.LOCATION option

Do you think it's an effective way to solve this compatibility problem?
Do you see an alternative?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use directly the [jgitver library](https://github.com/jgitver/jgitver) to participate into your build environment ; it is a pure java library.
The library is the base of both the [maven](https://github.com/jgitver/jgitver-maven-plugin) and [gradle](https://github.com/jgitver/gradle-jgitver-plugin) plugins.